# Comparing month and year from a date in Listview

Tags: excel, vba, date

i am trying to compare month and year from a date in Listview with following code  ....

```
If Text(ListView1.ListItems.SubItems(12),"mmm") = Me.CbMonth.Value And Year(ListView1.ListItems.SubItems(12)) = Me.CbYear.Text
```

however its giving error as "Method or Data member not found"

pls help

tried all  combinations of listview references to a subitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide an index for the desired listitem.  For example, if you want  the subitem for the first item in your list...

```
ListView1.ListItems(1).SubItems(12)
```

Comment: Thank you ...it solved the issue. ..... can you  also  suggest some good resources to  learn how to  generate word documents from excel VBA with complete control over the word lines , paragraphs,  their formatting , inserting tables and filling them up  from values from excel sheets etc